# GraphSAGE - Why are the weights for my edge prediction layer learnt but not for my aggregator layers?

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning, keras

I am making a GraphSAGE model with two aggregator layers, each having their own weights and biases. I also have an edge prediction layer to predict if two nodes are connected by an edge. Shown below is the function I used to calculate the loss and relevant functions. However, only the edge prediction layer's weights are being learned and not the weights of the aggregation layer.

By aggregating the node representations of neighbouring nodes, my model outputs the node representation for nodes I am interested in. These output is then used to calculate the loss which is obtained from the edge prediction layer.

Why is this so?

Code snippet to get loss in function used to train model:

```
...
              with tf.GradientTape() as tape:
                    
                    # Generate inputs to be fed into model
                    # Note: next_minibatch_feed_dict() feeds in the next batch of training edges
                    train_feed_dict = minibatch.next_minibatch_feed_dict()
                    self.inputs1 = train_feed_dict['batch1']
                    self.inputs2 = train_feed_dict['batch2']
                    self.batch_size = train_feed_dict['batch_size']

                    # Start taking note of training time
                    start_time = time.time()

                    # Pass in inputs to model and get outputs
                    input1_outputs, input2_outputs, neg_outputs = self.get_outputs()

                    # Run model on train inputs to get train_loss, train_mrr 
                    train_loss = self.calc_loss((input1_outputs, input2_outputs, neg_outputs))
                    train_loss = train_loss / tf.cast(self.batch_size, tf.float32)
...
```

Function to calculate loss:

```
def calc_loss(self, outputs):
        
        loss = 0.
        input1_outputs, input2_outputs, neg_outputs = outputs
        
        # Get aggregators
        aggregators = [self.layer0_aggregator, self.layer1_aggregator]
        
        # For each aggregator,
        for aggregator in aggregators:
    
            # Add l2 loss of aggregator's weights
            loss += self.params_decay * tf.nn.l2_loss(aggregator.neigh_weights)
            loss += self.params_decay * tf.nn.l2_loss(aggregator.self_weights)
            
            if aggregator.bias:
                loss += self.params_decay * tf.nn.l2_loss(aggregator.bias_vals)
            
        # Add loss from link prediction
        loss += self.link_predictor.loss(input1_outputs, input2_outputs, neg_outputs)
        
        tf.summary.scalar('loss', loss)
        return loss
```

Function to get outputs:

```
def get_outputs(self):
        
        # Prepare neg_nodes
        labels = tf.reshape(tf.cast(self.inputs2, dtype = tf.int64), [self.batch_size, 1])
        
        # Convert numpy array to list and flatten 2D list to a 1D list
        unigrams = self.degrees.flatten()
        unigrams = list(unigrams)
        
        self.neg_samples, _, _ = tf.nn.fixed_unigram_candidate_sampler(
            true_classes=labels,
            num_true=1,
            num_sampled=self.neg_sample_size,
            unique=False,
            range_max=len(self.degrees),
            distortion=0.75,
            unigrams=unigrams)
         
        # Get the samples and support_size for batch1, batch2 and neg_nodes in an array
        samples_input1, support_sizes_input1 = self.sample(self.inputs1, self.layer_infos)
        samples_input2, support_sizes_input2 = self.sample(self.inputs2, self.layer_infos)
        neg_samples, neg_support_sizes = self.sample(self.neg_samples, self.layer_infos, self.neg_sample_size)
        
        # Get number of samples
        num_samples = [layer_info.num_samples for layer_info in self.layer_infos]
        
        # Aggregate the samples and get output
        input1_outputs = self.aggregate(samples_input1, [self.features], self.dims, num_samples,
                                  support_sizes_input1, concat = self.concat, model_size = self.model_size)
        input2_outputs = self.aggregate(samples_input2, [self.features], self.dims, num_samples,
                                  support_sizes_input2, concat = self.concat, model_size = self.model_size)
        neg_outputs = self.aggregate(neg_samples, [self.features], self.dims, num_samples, neg_support_sizes,
                                     batch_size = self.neg_sample_size, concat = self.concat, model_size = self.model_size)        
        
        # return feature representation for batch 1 nodes, " for batch 2 nodes, " for negative output nodes
        return (input1_outputs, input2_outputs, neg_outputs)
```

Function to aggregate: (This calls the custom aggregator layer)

```
 def aggregate(self, samples, input_features, dims, num_samples, support_sizes, batch_size = None,
                 name = None, concat = False, model_size = 'small'):
           
        # Determine batch size
        if batch_size is None:
            batch_size = self.batch_size
            
        # hidden is a list that contains the embeddings or hidden representations of the node samples from each layer.
        # Each element in the hidden list corresponds to a layer, and the shape of each element is determined by the number 
        # of node samples in that layer.
        # hidden: [base nodes to get representation for, nodes 2 layers away (Layer 2), nodes 1 layer away (Layer 1)]
        hidden = [tf.nn.embedding_lookup(input_features, np.asarray(node_samples, dtype = np.int32)) for node_samples in samples]
               
        # Start aggregating by layers
        for layer in range(len(num_samples)):
                                    
            # After determining aggregators, start from hops furthest away until reach back to base parent node
            next_hidden = []
                        
            for hop in range(len(num_samples) - layer):
                
                # Determine dimension multiplier
                dim_mult = 2 if concat and layer != 0 else 1
                
                # Convert batch size from tensor to numpy if needed
                if tf.is_tensor(batch_size):
                    batch_size = batch_size.numpy()
                    
                # Shape: [dims for current layer, dims for neighbour layer, dims of current layer]
                neigh_dims = [batch_size*support_sizes[hop], num_samples[len(num_samples) - hop - 1], dim_mult*dims[layer]]

                # Doing aggregator(input_data) calls .call() and .build() implictly
                if hop == len(num_samples) - 1:
                    aggregated_res = self.layer1_aggregator((hidden[hop], tf.reshape(hidden[hop + 1], neigh_dims)))
                else:
                    aggregated_res = tf.nn.relu(self.layer0_aggregator((hidden[hop], tf.reshape(hidden[hop + 1], neigh_dims))))
                
                next_hidden.append(aggregated_res)
                
        # Re-assign hidden as new aggregated output
        hidden = next_hidden

        # Return node representation of base node
        return hidden[0]
```

.call() function in aggregator layer: (Takes in a batch of nodes I am interested in and the neighbours of those node)

```
    def _call(self, inputs):
        
        # Feature representation for base nodes, feature representation for neighbour nodes
        self_vecs, neigh_vecs = inputs
        input_batchsize = self_vecs.shape[0] # 50
        output_dim = self_vecs.shape[1] # 14
        
        # Perform dropout
        # neigh_vecs = tf.nn.dropout(neigh_vecs, self.dropout)
        # self_vecs = tf.nn.dropout(self_vecs, self.dropout)
        
        # Array to store output
        output_np = np.zeros(shape = (input_batchsize, output_dim), dtype = np.float32)

        # Aggregate for each base node in batch
        for i in range(len(self_vecs)):
            
            # shape: (14,)
            cur_node_features = self_vecs[i]
            # shape: (5.14)
            neigh_nodes_features = neigh_vecs[i]
            
            # Aggregate features of neighbours by taking the mean
            # shape: (14,)
            neigh_nodes_mean = tf.reduce_mean(neigh_nodes_features, axis = 0)
            
            # Expand dims to perform matmul operation
            # shape: (14, 1)
            neigh_nodes_mean = tf.expand_dims(neigh_nodes_mean, axis = 1)
            cur_node_features = tf.expand_dims(cur_node_features, axis = 1)
            
            # shape: (14, 1)
            from_neighs = tf.matmul(self.neigh_weights, neigh_nodes_mean)
            from_self = tf.matmul(self.self_weights, cur_node_features)
            
            # Element wise addition if not concatenating else concate
            if not self.concat:
                # output shape: (14,1)
                output = tf.add_n([from_neighs, from_self])
            else:
                output = tf.concat([from_neighs, from_self], axis = 1)
            
            # Reduce dimensions to add with bias
            # shape: (14,)
            output = tf.squeeze(output)

            # Add bias, depending on self.bias
            if self.bias:
                output += self.bias_vals
            
            # output_np[i] shape: (14,)
            # output shape: (14,)
            output_np[i] = output
        
        output = tf.convert_to_tensor(output_np, np.float32)
        return output
```